# Predict error for GLMs in R with number of rows

Tags: r, glm, predict

I am trying to get a prediction curve for a logistic glm in R. I create a new data frame but do not understand why I keep getting this error. Thank you for your help!

```
glm1 <- glm(dataset_presence$presence ~ dataset_presence$Int_Bk, data = dataset_presence, family = binomial, na.action = na.exclude)

newdat <- data.frame(Int_Bk = seq(min(dataset_presence$Int_Bk), max(dataset_presence$Int_Bk), length=50))

newdat$presence <- predict(glm1, newdata = newdat, type="response")
```

> Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, presence, value = c(0.862135653229272,  :
> replacement has 167 rows, data has 50
> In addition: Warning message:
> 'newdata' had 50 rows but variables found have 167 rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the model without the `data$variable` in the formula:

```
glm1 <- glm(presence ~ Int_Bk, data = dataset_presence, family = binomial, na.action = na.exclude)
```

Once you do that, your prediction will work.  That said, if you're trying to plot the curve, the `ggeffects` and `effects` package have some really useful functions.  For example, using the `Chile` data from the `carData` package:

```
library(ggeffects)
data("Chile", package="carData")

Chile <- Chile %>% 
  filter(vote %in% c("Y", "N"))
m2 <- glm(vote ~ age, data=Chile, family=binomial)

p <- ggpredict(m2, terms="age")
plot(p)
```

The `plot()` method for the `ggpredict` object produces a `ggplot`.

[image]